# Windows laptop works with Wi-Fi AP, phone claims it is connected but can't access Internet

Tags: wi-fi, internet

There's an Asus 240 MIMO Wifi access point. There's a laptop running Windows XP that uses that access point no problem for years so far. And there's an Android based HTC Desire S smartphone that has problems. The objective is to make the smartphone access the Internet via the Wifi access point.

I open "wireless networks" configuration pane, "enable" Wifi - it goes through "scanning" and "obtaining IP address" stages, says "connected to TheRightNetworkName". The Wifi symbol is displayed in the bar under the top of the screen. Yet when I try to open any page in a browser if wouldn't do so and claim there were problems accessing that page.

I tried the following (listed in [this answer below](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14968/windows-laptop-uses-wifi-access-point-but-android-smartphone-claims-it-is-connec/14980#14980), thanks to [user Matthew Read](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/1465/matthew-read)):

- rebooted the phone - doesn't help
- checked MAC filtering on the AP - it is disabled
- disabled the firewall on the AP - doesn't help
- tried to change channels - doesn't help, the AP has 13 channels if that matters
- tried to change to 2.4 GHz - looks like it is already the only option, couldn't find any way to change the range
- didn't try to switch from WPA that is currently used to WEP because it feels quite scary - I can mess things up
- tried switching modes - b, g, b/g - doesn't help

How do I debug and resolve this issue?

Comment: What kind of security is on the network? WEP? WPA? It almost sounds like the network is using Mac address filtering.

Comment: @PortableWorld: WPA is used, no MAC filtering, I updated the question to include my findings.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you are using DHCP on your phone; if you have a static DNS set and it's the wrong one, you won't be able to browse the web.  Go to `Settings->Wireless And Network->Wi-Fi settings`, hit the context button (or right click button, or whatever you call it), select `Advanced`, and make sure `Use Static IP` is unchecked.

Comment: DHCP is used - checked that already.

Comment: As a complete shot in the dark, have you tried using a browser other than stock and seeing if that works?

Comment: Yes, I tried Firefox - results are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the smartphone connects to the AP as you say, try the following.

- Take the IP of the phone.
- Connect to the same AP your laptop
- Run `ping ip_of_phone` from cmd (if you are using win) or from Terminal
- If you can **do** a ping means that something is wrong, perhaps with the DNS
- If you can **not** ping, probably something is wrong with IP assignment. Perhaps a two devices have the same IP. A common mistake is that people assign an IP to an AP and do not exlude that IP from the DHCP pool of the router.

Comment: I tried that - ping succeeds. What else can I check?

Comment: Can you try using staic IP (whatever IP you are getting for the phone) and in DNS use 4.2.2.2 and 8.8.8.8

Answer (score 0):

First ensure the phone is using the right password for the network and try rebooting the phone.

Then play with with your AP, one of these at a time:

- Reboot it
- Ensure MAC filtering isn't on
- Try disabling any firewall it might have
- Ensure it uses channel 1 or 6 or 11 (assuming you're in an 11-channel region)
- Try switching to 2.4 GHz if it's broadcasting on the 5.0 GHz band
- Try switching from WPA to WEP encryption or vice-versa
- Try switching to or from mixed mode (e.g. 802.11 b/g rather than just 802.11b, etc.)

If nothing changes, please provide your phone model and I'll try to help further.

Comment: I checked everything except switching to WEP - that feels very risky. I updated the question to include my findings and phone and AP model.

Comment: @sharptooth Fair enough. Does the phone work OK on other Wi-Fi networks?

Comment: Yes, it works on another WPA-protected network okay.