# Where do I configure DNS and IP settings in HTC Desire S?

Tags: wi-fi, internet, htc-desire-s, dns

HTC Desire S seems to have very scarce WiFi settings. I'm trying to debug [a Wifi connectivity issue](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/14968/1097) and looks like [it might be a DNS problem](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14968/windows-laptop-uses-wifi-access-point-but-android-smartphone-claims-it-is-connec/14983#14983). I Googled and looks like many Android devices have some "advanced" settings including DNS server addresses. I can't find anything like that in Desire S.

What am I doing wrong? How do I change DNS and IP settings in Desire S?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my HTC Desire I find it under:

Settings-> Wireless & networks -> WiFi Settings

Press Menu and select Advanced

Here I can see option to use static IP by selecting "Use static IP"

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't realize I had to press Menu.

Answer (score 2):

OK just found it. In wifi settings press and hold the connected network you want to set IP to. Pick *modify network* and in there you scroll down, to *DHCP settings* and pick *static* and scroll down to et your IP. Kinda complicated comparing to non sense android. O well. Hope that helps OP or any other fellow searcher.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have HTC sense (you're using other ROM). Hence you don't have those settings. I use Hox with Sense as well as OP myself, and I don't see any options there to set a static IP. HTC seems to have disregarded those settings. (ICS 4.0.4)