# Galaxy Mini can't connect to the Internet over Wi-Fi

Tags: wi-fi, samsung-galaxy-mini

I purchased a Galaxy Mini with 2.2.1 a few days ago and I can connect to my home network (the wireless icon appears) but I can't surf on the Internet. I verified it got an IP correctly and tried many suggestions but no luck. It worked once at home and on a friend's network.

My router is a wireless-n Linksys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds more like inconsistent wifi settings.

Since your phone shows its connected, try to visit your **router's web interface** through the phone to see if its connected properly. (note that please use stock browser and no proxies for now) If this doesn't work, most likely its the problem with wrong password or security mode like WEP/WPA.

If the above works, then I suspect you to have a DNS problem. A rooted phone can let you [custom-set the DNS](https://market.android.com/details?id=uk.co.mytechie.setDNS&hl=en) on your phone. Try to set it to Google's DNS. 
Just to confirm if its a DNS problem, try entering an IP address of a website rather than the domain name.

Comment: it's solved :), just remove DNS from router setting and enjoy ^_^

Answer (score 2):

A few things to try:

- Reboot your device
- Change the router to use 802.11b/g instead of 802.11n
- Change the router channel (to 1, 6, or 11 if using North American channels)
- Change the security from WEP to WPA or vice-versa
- Ensure you have no MAC filtering or firewall rules on the router
- Switch the router from using the 5.0 GHz band to the 2.4 GHz band, or vice-versa
- Other suggestions posted in answer to [Windows laptop works with Wi-Fi AP, phone claims it is connected but can't access Internet](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/14968/1465)

Comment: unfortunately, nothing helps :'(...is there any hope ??

Answer (score 0):

I have been using Galaxy Mini for the last 2 years. WiFi is working with normal network. But in our company, advanced WiFi mobile is not responding. After Googling, I found out this phone does not have 'direct WiFi' options like higher-end phones (eg. Galaxy SII).

I suggest you change the phone!

Comment: I don't quite understand why Direct WiFi is required for connecting to Internet via WiFi? Direct WiFi is required only to connect to other WiFi devices (other than access point/router) to share data like files etc.